# How to filter from a list of static texts through the name of a label

Tags: swift, xcuitest, xcuielement

This:

```
let car = app.descendants(matching: .any)["car_view_81"]
```

Returns:

```
↪︎Find: Elements matching predicate '"car_view_81" IN identifiers'
  Output: {
    StaticText, 0x153216ec0, {{167.5, 316.7}, {58.0, 19.7}}, identifier: 'car_view_81', label: 'Car'
    Image, 0x153216fe0, {{60.0, 358.3}, {30.0, 30.0}}, identifier: 'car_view_81'
    StaticText, 0x153217100, {{306.8, 365.6}, {22.3, 15.3}}, identifier: 'car_view_81', label: '13%'
    StaticText, 0x153217220, {{59.8, 423.6}, {30.3, 15.3}}, identifier: 'car_view_81', label: 'Draw'
    StaticText, 0x153217340, {{305.5, 423.6}, {25.0, 15.3}}, identifier: 'car_view_81', label: '33%'
    Image, 0x153217460, {{60.0, 474.3}, {30.0, 30.0}}, identifier: 'car_view_81'
    StaticText, 0x153217580, {{305.5, 481.6}, {25.0, 15.3}}, identifier: 'car_view_81', label: '54%'
  }
```

There's multiple static text elements that's within this view.

I want to filter by label "Draw", to check that this static text exists.

I have tried:

```
car.staticTexts["Draw"].firstMatch
```

Which doesn't appear to filter.

I have also tried a predicate `("label == "Draw"")`, but that also doesn't seem to filter:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS[c] 'Draw'")

let car_view = app.staticTexts["car_view_81"]

return car_view.staticTexts.containing(predicate).element
```

How can I filter from a list of identifiers that a `.descendants` function returns please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.staticTexts.matching(identifier: "car_view_81")
               .containing(XCUIElement.ElementType.staticText, identifier: "Draw")
               .element
```

Solved my problem.

Using `.matching` for obtaining the `XCUIElementQuery` of the `car_view_81` and then calling the `containing` filter to extract the "Draw" element.

Answer (score 1):

`car` comes back to you as an `XCUIElementQuery`.

We want to find an element in that `XCUIElementQuery`.

`car.element(...)` is a good function for that.

I'd love to call this function:

```
func element(
  matching elementType: XCUIElement.ElementType,
  identifier: String?
) -> XCUIElement
```

But I'm a little rusty on XCUITest and don't have any test code with me so I can't know if it will fall back to trying a label if an identifier exists, but doesn't match.

So we're stuck (or at least safest) matching by predicate `func element(matching predicate: NSPredicate)`

```
let car = app.descendants(matching: .any)["car_view_81"]
let drawPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "type == 'staticText' AND label == 'Draw'")
return car.element(predicate: drawPredicate)
```

Ref: [XCUIElementQuery docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery)